# How to improve predict performance using proxy to target signal?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have a regression problem in a supervised learning setting. To put it formally, given an input `x` and a target `y`, I want to learn a mapping function `y^ = f(x)` such that `y^~y` for all `X`. For this particular problem, it is hard to achieve good performance because the input `x` is somewhat incomplete. So even for a human, it could be difficult to guess `y` correctly. To make things worse, the amount of data available for training is quite limited, by modern DL standards.

Now, let's say that I also have access, **only during training time**, to a signal `u`, which is a proxy for `y`. `u` is similar to a guess; most times it agrees to `y`, sometimes it doesn't.

My question is: how can I incorporate this `u` signal into my model training to improve predictive performance? (this could be either obtaining a higher overall score or the same score but using fewer samples)

My feeling is that something like this must have been studied before, but I am a bit lost and don't know where/what to look for. My initial thoughts are that maybe `u` could be used as some sort of prior, at least making the model less data-hungry. But I also don't know how to implement this.

My current model is in the form of a neural network, so I would prefer solutions that fit with this. But I'm also open to changing it if needed.

Comment: If U is simply a proxy for Y, and it is only available during training when you have access to the true Y, I don't see how it can be utilized to improve the model.

Comment: the thing is that U is generated based on, among other things, some of this missing information in X. So that's why I think it could be useful in improving the predictive performance of the model. But don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you. I'm assuming based on your comment that U is modeled on X and that it is deterministic.

1. If you know that U is a good approximation of Y, and especially if you expect that U is a better estimate for Y then what you would be able to come up with by regressing just Y~X, you can choose to model U~X instead of Y~X. It is possible, especially if you have an idea of the nature of the model U~X, that you can identify exact model U~X which will then serve as an effective proxy for the model Y~X. U will be easier to model since it does not incorporate random noise.
2. One method of missing value imputation is to predict missing values based on the non-missing values of other variables. For example, if X1 is missing, you can take the observations that aren't missing X1 and train a linear model $X_1\sim X_2+X_3+...+X_k$. You can then apply this model to predict the X1 values in observations where the true value of X1 is missing. If you pursue this method, it is very likely that U will be an informative predictor of the missing values, and you can include it in your model $X_1\sim X_2+X_3+...+X_k+U$.

Comment: thanks Ryan. In the second suggestion, it is not clear to me how I would then use X1, since during inference time I don't have U available to predict X1. Could you elaborate?

Comment: That is a good point @user244109. You would have to employ a different strategy to impute X1 during prediction. The benefit of the second suggestion is simply that it increases the amount of accurate training data you have which may allow you to learn a better model.